# How do I best use a fit statistic like chi-squared fit for a model that predicts two independent sets of measurements?

Tags: chi-squared-test, optimization, goodness-of-fit, fitting

I have a model $M(\vec{x})$ for a vector of model parameters $\vec{x}$ that predicts two sets of measurements that I have taken - $v(h)$ and $L(h)$. The two independent data sets each have their own respective uncertainties, and each of these data vectors have different samplings (i.e. the length of the two data vectors are not the same).

If I only needed to fit one of these data vectors, I would do a $\chi^{2}$ fit and be done with it, but I am not sure what the formal and rigorous way of approaching this problem is - Do I combine the $\chi^{2}$ values in some way? Since the lengths of the data vectors are different, what is that way?

I have quite a bit of experience with statistics, but I have not found a meaningful discussion of this problem. I have done a few tests combining fit statistics from the independent data in different ways, to varying degrees of satisfaction.

Answer (score -1):

I have been thinking about this more, but I think the answer is that you use the sum of the two $\chi^{2}$ values and optimize that. From the frequentist perspective, data is simply data. It does not matter if each data point is actually a different measurement - only what the uncertainty on that measurement is.